# Heroku-docker not working on osx

Tags: heroku, docker, dropwizard, heroku-postgres, docker-machine

I am developing api using heroku/java with dropwizard framework and using postgres add-ons of heroku.

Following [heroku-docker](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/docker) guidelines, `docker ps` showing status `Up About an hour` but not working with VM ip address:port. using `docker-machine ip default` to get VM ip.